# Combo filtering with isotope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am trying to filter between 6 categories with isotope. I currently have it working so if `cat1` is selected, it shows `cat1` items, however if I select `cat1` and `cat2`, then it shows both `cat1` and `cat2` items. What I want it to do is only show items that has **BOTH** `cat1` and `cat2`. Not just show them separately. Is this possible?

**Here is my combofilter**

```
var data = {
  accredited: 'seo social-media lead-generation marketing-automation blogging email-marketing'.split(' '),  
};


function getComboFilter( filters ) {
  var i = 0;
  var comboFilters = [];
  var message = [];

  for ( var prop in filters ) {
    message.push( filters[ prop ].join(' ') );
    var filterGroup = filters[ prop ];
    // skip to next filter group if it doesn't have any values
    if ( !filterGroup.length ) {
      continue;
    }
    if ( i === 0 ) {
      // copy to new array
      comboFilters = filterGroup.slice(0);
    } else {
      var filterSelectors = [];
      // copy to fresh array
      var groupCombo = comboFilters.slice(0); // [ A, B ]
      // merge filter Groups
      for (var k=0, len3 = filterGroup.length; k < len3; k++) {
        for (var j=0, len2 = groupCombo.length; j < len2; j++) {
          filterSelectors.push( groupCombo[j] + filterGroup[k] ); // [ 1, 2 ]
        }

      }
      // apply filter selectors to combo filters for next group
      comboFilters = filterSelectors;
    }
    i++;
  }

  var comboFilter = comboFilters.join(', ');
  return comboFilter;
}
```

**Here is the example of my buttons (checkboxes)**

```
<div class="examples-filter-button-container" id="filterButtons">
        <div class="filter-buttons" data-group="accredited">
           <label>
              <input class="ex-button" type="checkbox" name="SEO" value=".SEO"><span>SEO</span>
           </label>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selectors for isotope filtering,

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/filtering.html

So

```
$container.isotope({ filter: ".cat1.cat2" });
```

Will show only elements that have both classes